# How to check the current MetaMask network?

Tags: web3js, metamask, networkid

How to check the current MetaMask network?

For example, if the current network is Rinkeby, I need the string `"rinkeby"`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check the current network chain ID like this:

```
console.log(window.ethereum.networkVersion, 'window.ethereum.networkVersion');
```

And these are the chain IDs for the most used ethereum networks:

1. Mainnet: 1
2. Kovan: 42
3. Ropsten: 3
4. Rinkeby: 4
5. Goerli: 5

Comment: `typeof` `window.ethereum.networkVersion` is `string`.

Comment: I never said it's not a string, it's the network ID represented as string.

Comment:   yeah,  I just added it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Is there a place I can find all chain ids ? Lets say if I want to know the chain id of matic main chain, where should I check. Sorry if this is a dumb question. Newbie here !

Comment: @TheEhsanSarshar very important note, thank you! Because when you listen to the chainChanged event it returns a number.

Comment: @vishnusatis developer docs

Answer (score 2):

@vishnusatis check this website to find all chain ids. https://chainlist.org/