# Ethers npm metamask differentiate ropsten and mainnet

Tags: ether, metamask, ropsten, react

In ethers npm

I want to only allow payments
If the users in on the metamask
Eth mainnet and not ropsten

So after they make a payment
I can logged it in the database
As paid,

But I don’t want to log it in the
Database if the user has paid with
Ropsten ,

So something like

```
Network = ethers Get network()
If (network === ropsten) { return }


If (network === mainnet){
Database. Log user with id 727!he3 
Paid 
}
```

Because now the users can pay with
Ropsten and I can’t tell this
From
The transaction receipt or when calling getsigner() ???
If it was ropsten or mainnet

Answer (score 1):

You can read the current network chain ID from metamask like this:

```
console.log(window.ethereum.networkVersion, 'window.ethereum.networkVersion');// that will be of type string
```

So your logic will look something like this:

```
network = window.ethereum.networkVersion 

if (network !== "1") {return;} else { Database. Log user with id 727!he3 Paid }
```

And these are the chain IDs for the most used ethereum networks:

- Mainnet: 1
- Kovan: 42
- Ropsten: 3
- Rinkeby: 4
- Goerli: 5

If you are even going to different chains you cn find a list of the ids [here](https://chainlist.org).

More discussion about it can be found on this other [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/85194/how-to-check-the-current-metamask-network).